# Should calculation requests be a GET or POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm building some services with ASP.NET Web API to perform calculations. Should the requests be GETs or POSTs?

The calculations will have 0..n parameters, but most likely 3-6. I plan to put the parameters in the body as json. This leads me to think I should be using POSTs.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are the calculations idempotent? If so, you should use GET.

Comment: @BradM - Yes. These are scientific / mathematical calculations and given the same values a second time, the actions should return the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the calculations are idempotent, you should use GET. Browsers may cache these requests by default (which I assume for your application is a good thing). Also, there will be no annoying "postback data to server" or whatever popups.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the idempotent nature of a calculation in terms of an API, consider two examples:

1. An increment counter endpoint `/counter` which increments by `1` and returns the current integer value of the counter every time it is invoked.
2. An addition endpoint `/add?x=2&y=3` that takes two parameters x and y and sums them up and responds with the result (5 in this case).

The second example is that of an idempotent calculation, i.e. given the same x & y over and over again, it will return the same result and hence should be a `GET` method. The first example however, will return a different result each time it is invoked, even though the parameters/request body does not change. Thus it should be marked as a `POST` method.